# Number to Decimal Format with Four Decimal extra

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angularjs 1.xx

```
var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')
     .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");  

if(transformedInput!="")
     transformedInput="$"+transformedInput;
```

> Input = 123456789, Output =  $123,456,789

But I need the following output:

> Input = 20.56, Output =  $20.5600
>
> Input = 20, Output =  $20.0000
>
> Input = 20.567, Output =  $20.5670

Comment: Did you try `{{ amount | currency : '$' : 4 }}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Without using filters.

Use parseFloat to convert string to float then use toFixed(4)

```js
var text = "20";
var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')
                .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

                 if(transformedInput!="")
                transformedInput="$"+parseFloat(transformedInput).toFixed(4);
                
                console.log(transformedInput);
```

Comment: not working like i need
trying to input      :  123456789
expecting output :  $123,456,789
Current Output    :  $123.0000

Answer (score 0):

> Use Angular currency filter

```
        <span data-ng-bind="'123456789'| currency : '$' : 4 "></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this implementation will work for you.

```js
var msg = document.getElementById('myInputBox'),
 btn = document.getElementById('formatButton');
    
btn.addEventListener('click', getFormattedData);

function checkNumeric(str) {
    return str.replace(/\,|\$/g, '');
}

Number.prototype.format = function() {
    return this.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
};

function getFormattedData() {
 var num = checkNumeric(msg.value),
        val = (Number(num).toFixed(4)).toString().split('.'),
        decimal = '';
        
    if (num.indexOf('.') > -1) {
        decimal = '.' + val[1];
    }
  
    msg.value = '$' + Number(val[0]).format() + decimal;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id='myInputBox' value="" />
<input type="button" id="formatButton" value='Get Output'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got the built-in [`Number#toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) which is exactly meant for this :

```js
var nbs = [20.56, 20, 20.567];

var $s = nbs.map(n =>
  n.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    style: 'currency', // that's money
    currency: 'USD', // that's $
    // the difficult (?) part
    // we need to get the length of digits before "."
    minimumSignificantDigits: ((~~n) + '').length + 4
  })
);

console.log($s);
```